# Laravel JWT Best Practice - Authorize, Middleware & Database

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I just begin to explore [Laravel's JWT Authorisation](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki),
I'd successfully install it on my Laravel 5.1 and authorize it and test via [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en).

**Best Practice**
has come to my mind, I'd saw some [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523238/best-practices-for-server-side-handling-of-jwt-tokens) on stackoverflow regarding about JWT best practices, But I'm not sure currently am I doing it correctly my Laravel Application?

**1. Refresh Token**

Below are my **config/jwt.php** settings that follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739167/jwt-json-web-token-automatic-prolongation-of-expiration)'s suggestion that on JWT's UX

```
'ttl' => 10080, //1week
'refresh_ttl' => 60, // 1 hours
```

**2. Middleware**

Is this the best way to wrap a simple JWT API middleware to have jwt auth & refresh middleware?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth', 'jwt.refresh'], function() {
        Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
        Route::get('authenticate/user', 'AuthenticateController@getAuthenticatedUser');
        Route::get('authenticate/logout', 'AuthenticateController@logout');
        //Other api call that modify user's db....
        Route::post('update_address/', 'otherAPIController@update_address');
        Route::post('update_password/', 'otherAPIController@update_password');
        Route::post('insert_other_stuff/', 'otherAPIController@insert_other_stuff');
    });
});
```

**3. Database**

The best is not to heavy modify it default users database?
below is my database structure

```
users : 
- id,uuid,name,email,password,remember_token,created_at,updated_at

users_information :
- id,uuid,address,telephone,first_name,last_name,created_at,updated_at
```

or may be having

```
users_role :
- id,uuid,role_id,role_group,role_description,created_at,updated_at
```

is it good to separate user's tables and we query other information as we authorise JWT with the valid_token using user's **uuid** value?

Comment: Auth::user() is current user who is signed in, no need to separate,just like normal session login.