# How do popular websites get a secure authentication flow?

Tags: authentication, jwt, session-cookies, xss, csrf

I'm creating an application with a react.js frontend and a node.js REST API backend.

When searching how to handle authentication mechanism, the answers are always the same, using JWT VS session ID and storing in local storage VS cookies, with the following warnings:

- `Local storage is vulnerable to XSS, don't do it`
- `Cookies are vulnerable to CSRF, even if they are httponly and secure, don't do it`
- `Double Submit Cookies method is vulnerable to XSS`

Basically, it seems whichever solution we chose, we will always be vulnerable to either XSS or CSRF.

I don't get it. It's 2020, and it seems no secure authentication mechanism exist? But then,

- Does it mean stackoverflow.com is vulnerable to XSS or CSRF?
- Does it mean facebook.com is vulnerable to XSS or CSRF?
- Does it mean twitter.com is vulnerable to XSS or CSRF?
- Does it mean google.com is vulnerable to XSS or CSRF?
- Does it mean amazon.com is vulnerable to XSS or CSRF?

I don't get it.

I think these websites ARE secure regarding authentication, while they don't all use 2 factor authentication nor OAuth nor ask the user to login again at each page refresh.

So why is everybody telling everybody there are 2 solutions (one vulnerable to XSS and one vulnerable to CSRF) if all those websites are secure? How do they secure their authentication and why couldn't we do the same?

Comment: There are some comprehensive and nuanced responses for server side and client side scenarios here: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452896/authentication-jwt-usage-vs-session 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340275/where-to-save-a-jwt-in-a-browser-based-application-and-how-to-use-it

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'one size fits all' solution and it really depends on your situation. For example, how effective your XSS protection is might depend on how heavily you rely on CDNs. If you want to be as secure as possible you need to understand your situation and the drawbacks to your potential solutions to figure out if you can make changes in your architecture to support a solution.

I suggest for a simple general implementation that you store the JWT in an httpOnly Cookie so it can't be accessed by malicious javascript and store your CSRF token in localStorage so it can't be accessed by a CSRF attacker.